# Creating Many Small XML files in Hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

I have a large dataset in Hadoop with data for many different customers.

Each customer can have many order items in this data set, where many can range from a few hundred to millions per day.

The data set has about 50,000 customers.

What I need to do, is create a daily XML report for each customer, where the data for each customer is in its own file. This means that some files will be tiny, but others will be quite large (the XML representation is quite verbose and has many fields).

Writing the Map Reduce code to produce the XML is trivial, and my first approach to this problem was to use the Hadoop Multiple Outputs to write a file per customer in the reducer. While this works, all these small files are going to put a lot of pressure on Namenode. In addition, I need to export all these files out of the Hadoop cluster and put them on a standard filesystem where a web application will serve them, so exporting lots of files like this may give problems too.

Another idea I came up with, was to create a single Sequence file, with the key equal to the customer and the value containing the XML for a single transaction, pre sorted in the order that would make up the XML report. Then I can export a single sequence file and code up a simple standalone Java program to read the sequence file(s) and write out a file for each customer. I have tested this on a small data set and hopefully performance would be ok.

Has anyone else come up against a problem like this with Hadoop and have any other ideas about how to solve this problem?

Does the sequence file approach sound like a sensible way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Using the [MapFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html) as storage might solve your problem very well. MapFile is a sorted SequenceFile where it additionally maintains an **index file** which will be used to seek the keys faster from the map.

You may compose a MapFile from your job, where the key could be the customer id and the value could be xml contents, behind the scenes the MapFile creates an index file which will maintain the offset of the customer id keys.

By this way all your customer's xml files will be composed within a Mapfile which eliminates the small file problem, So that your namenode may breath easily :).

After this you may export the Mapfile to any application, you will not be needed to write the contents of the MapFile to disk, wherein you can very well reuse the MapFile itself to retrieve the customer xml contents out of by looking up customer id and the MapFile  will support fast look up with the help of the index file. Please refer,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/887028/Implementing-Joins-in-Hadoop-Map-Reduce-using-MapF

The [BloomMapFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/BloomMapFile.html) variant of MapFile claims to provide more faster lookups for key which may help you better. Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks for the information. MapFiles sound potentially very useful - I will have to experiment with them and see how I can use them for my problem.